# Using bootstrap pagination with standard set controller

Tags: pagination

I am trying to implement bootstrap pagination wherein page numbers are displayed  along with first,last,next and previous buttons. I understand standard set controller provides native methods for accessing first,last,next,previous records. But how can I access records by clicking the page number buttons.

Comment: Have you tried method setpageNumber ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're building exactly but you could try [Youreka](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000E6jHqEAJ) for free from the AppExchange.  It's all drag and drop. It will let you connect to any object/record, natively supports pagination, dependent questions and a series of different types of questions that link back to your Salesforce data.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000E6jHqEAJ